# Trying to anchor to a reusable component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href, anchor

I have a component that uses a database array {row.title} to generate rows containing video carousels.  The title for each row comes from an array and I want to add an anchor tag to images at the top of the page that will go to the first row title, next image clicked goes to the second row, etc. How do I specify what the href should look at if the row titles can change and there is no unique id?

Do I need to add a unique id? I can't do href=#specific_text as the text can change.